# Using google spreadsheet api with OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-sheets, gdata, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

As Google has deprecated use of OAuth1, I am trying to migrate my application to OAuth2. I am using Service Account and trying to read a Google spreadsheet. I am able to get the access token but still not able to get the spreadsheets associated with my account.Below is the code I am using,please let me know where am I making a mistake. :

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        String SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full";
        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
        String[] SCOPESArray = { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" };
        final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId("28031770151-826a7iuekrsmr0gf4kc####iiop@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
                .build();

        System.out.println(credential.getAccessToken());
        credential.refreshToken();
        credential.getRefreshToken();
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("inlaid-chassis-9640");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
```

//          spreadsheets comes out be a blank array

Answer (score 1):

Solved! For this we need to share our spreadsheet with the service account id/email Id(refer the code above) generated while creating the project on https://console.developers.google.com.